# Trying to pass properties/ combine components, to stack in a Button's attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've been working with some boiler-plate code for a while now... and am trying to customize it but am having trouble. For a bit of background; there is two aspects of the project I am working with. The first being, the "Upload data" portion of code which consists of a component that takes input from the web-page and transfers to MongoDB database. And the second being the, "Add to cart" portion, which takes the data from the MongoDB database and adds to cart. As the boiler-plate goes, these two components are separate. One is dedicated to a "submit" data button on an "Upload" web-page, the other is dedicated to an "add to cart" button on a different web-page. I am trying to merge both of these into one button. So when I click "submit" the data is sent to server, then retrieved and added to cart.

I have tried many different approaches to this but am stuck. I've been playing around with props but am just in way over my head. This is the code I am working with.

"UploadProductPageClassComponent.js"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Typography, Button, Form, Input } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';
import FileUpload from '../../utils/FileUpload';

const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;

const Continents = [
    { key: 1, value: "Africa" },
    { key: 2, value: "Europe" },
    { key: 3, value: "Asia" },
    { key: 4, value: "North America" },
    { key: 5, value: "South America" },
    { key: 6, value: "Australia" },
    { key: 7, value: "Antarctica" }
]

export class UploadProductPage extends Component {

    state = {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        continents: 1,
        images: [],
        price: 0
    }

    handleChangeTitle = (event) => {
        this.setState({ title: event.currentTarget.value })
    }

    handleChangePrice = (event) => {
        this.setState({ price: parseInt(event.currentTarget.value, 10) })
    }

    handleChangeDecsription = (event) => {
        // console.log(event.currentTarget.value)
        this.setState({ description: event.currentTarget.value })
    }

    handleChangeContinents = (event) => {
        this.setState({ continents: event.currentTarget.value })
    }

    onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (this.props.user.userData && !this.props.user.userData.isAuth) {
            return alert('Please Log in First')
        }

        if (!this.state.title || !this.state.description ||
            !this.state.continents || !this.state.images
            || !this.state.price) {
            return alert('Please first fill all the fields')
        }

        const variables = {
            writer: this.props.user.userData._id,
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
            images: this.state.images,
            continents: this.state.continents,
            price: this.state.price
        }

        axios.post('/api/product/uploadProduct', variables)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    alert('video Uploaded Successfully')
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.props.history.push('/')
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to upload video')
                }
            })
    }

    updateFiles = (newImages) => {
        this.setState({ images: newImages })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ maxWidth: '700px', margin: '2rem auto' }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                <Title level={2} > Upload Travel Product</Title>
            </div>

            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

               <FileUpload refreshFunction={this.updateFiles} />

                <br /><br />
                <label>Title</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={this.handleChangeTitle}
                    value={this.state.title}
                />
                <br /><br />
                <label>Description</label>
                <TextArea
                    onChange={this.handleChangeDecsription}
                    value={this.state.description}
                />
                <br /><br />
                <label>Price($)</label>
                <Input
                    type="number"
                    onChange={this.handleChangePrice}
                    value={this.state.price}
                />
                <br /><br />
                <select onChange={this.handleChangeContinents}>
                    {Continents.map(item => (
                        <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>{item.value}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <br /><br />

                <Button type="primary" size="large" onClick={onSubmit}>
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UploadProductPage
```

"UploadProductPage.js"

```
import { Typography, Button, Form, message, Input, Icon } from 'antd';
import FileUpload from '../../utils/FileUpload'
import ProductInfo from '../DetailProductPage/Sections/ProductInfo'
import Axios from 'axios';

const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;

const Continents = [
    { key: 1, value: "Africa" },
    { key: 2, value: "Europe" },
    { key: 3, value: "Asia" },
    { key: 4, value: "North America" },
    { key: 5, value: "South America" },
    { key: 6, value: "Australia" },
    { key: 7, value: "Antarctica" }
]

function UploadProductPage(props) {

    const [TitleValue, setTitleValue] = useState("")
    const [DescriptionValue, setDescriptionValue] = useState("")
    const [PriceValue, setPriceValue] = useState(0)
    const [ContinentValue, setContinentValue] = useState(1)

    const [Images, setImages] = useState([])


    const onTitleChange = (event) => {
        setTitleValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onDescriptionChange = (event) => {
        setDescriptionValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onPriceChange = (event) => {
        setPriceValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onContinentsSelectChange = (event) => {
        setContinentValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const updateImages = (newImages) => {
        setImages(newImages)
    }
    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();


        if (!TitleValue || !DescriptionValue || !PriceValue ||
            !ContinentValue || !Images) {
            return alert('fill all the fields first!')
        }

        const variables = {
            writer: props.user.userData._id,
            title: TitleValue,
            description: DescriptionValue,
            price: PriceValue,
            images: Images,
            continents: ContinentValue,
        }

        Axios.post('/api/product/uploadProduct', variables)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    alert('Product Successfully Uploaded')
                    props.history.push('/')
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to upload Product')
                }
            })

    }

    return (
        <div style={{ maxWidth: '700px', margin: '2rem auto' }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                <Title level={2}> Upload Travel Product</Title>
            </div>


            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} >

                {/* DropZone */}
                <FileUpload refreshFunction={updateImages} />

                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Title</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onTitleChange}
                    value={TitleValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Description</label>
                <TextArea
                    onChange={onDescriptionChange}
                    value={DescriptionValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Price($)</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onPriceChange}
                    value={PriceValue}
                    type="number"
                />
                <br /><br />
                <select onChange={onContinentsSelectChange} value={ContinentValue}>
                    {Continents.map(item => (
                        <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>{item.value} </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <br />
                <br />

                <Button 
                    onClick={onSubmit}
                >
                    Submit
                </Button>

            </Form>

        </div>
    )
}

export default UploadProductPage
```

In the above code, which describes the "upload data to server" process, what I have been trying to do is mess with the "onClick" attribute. I am trying to combine the "onSubmit" with "addToCarthandler" in the code below (which handles the adding to cart). But nothing I am trying is working and I am not sure if it is even possible.

"DetailProductPage.js"

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Descriptions } from 'antd';

function ProductInfo(props) { 

    const [Product, setProduct] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {

        setProduct(props.detail)

    }, [props.detail])

    const addToCarthandler = () => {
        props.addToCart(props.detail._id)
    }


    return (
        <div> 
            <Descriptions title="Product Info">
                <Descriptions.Item label="Price"> {Product.price}</Descriptions.Item>
                <Descriptions.Item label="Sold">{Product.sold}</Descriptions.Item>
                <Descriptions.Item label="View"> {Product.views}</Descriptions.Item>
                <Descriptions.Item label="Description"> {Product.description}</Descriptions.Item>
            </Descriptions>

            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Button size="large" shape="round" type="danger"
                    onClick={addToCarthandler}
                >
                    Add to Cart
                    </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductInfo
```

"ProductInfo.js"

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import ProductImage from './Sections/ProductImage';
import ProductInfo from './Sections/ProductInfo';
import { addToCart } from '../../../_actions/user_actions';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
function DetailProductPage(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productId = props.match.params.productId
    const [Product, setProduct] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get(`/api/product/products_by_id?id=${productId}&type=single`)
            .then(response => {
                setProduct(response.data[0])
            })

    }, [])

    const addToCartHandler = (productId) => {
        dispatch(addToCart(productId))
    }

    return (
        <div className="postPage" style={{ width: '100%', padding: '3rem 4rem' }}>

            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <h1>{Product.title}</h1>
            </div>

            <br />

            <Row gutter={[16, 16]} >
                <Col lg={12} xs={24}>
                    <ProductImage detail={Product} />
                </Col>
                <Col lg={12} xs={24}>
                    <ProductInfo
                        addToCart={addToCartHandler}
                        detail={Product} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DetailProductPage
```

I am adding below the code for the 
If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it. I've been stuck on this for so long and it's really starting to sadden me. Thanks.

Comment: When you say, "I am trying to merge both of these into one button. So when I click "submit" the data is sent to server, then retrieved and added to cart.", I'm a little bit confused here... can you maybe elaborate a bit?

Comment: Hey! Yes. I'm trying to make 1 button have 2 functions essentially. So in the code above, under the UploadProductPage.js file, there is a "Button" being returned with the attribute "onClick = {onSubmit}". This is submitting data to database. I am wondering if I can also have that same button "add to cart" using the "onClick = {addToCarthandler}" function in the DetailProductPage.js.

Comment: You can. Just give one button's onClick prop `onSubmit` and the other button's onClick prop `addToCartHandler`? If that doesn't answer your question I must be missing something here.

Comment: That's what I have right now. But wouldn't that mean there's 2 buttons? I would like to have just 1.

Comment: You have two different pages right? That means you have two different buttons.

Comment: Yes, there's two different pages. But I don't have a need for the page that contains the "add to cart" button, hence why I would like to have the "submit"  just handle the adding to cart function. Would I have to rewrite it to make 1 component?

Comment: The Button component you're using is the same in both cases already. Because both buttons are on different screens, they are mounted to different parts of the DOM. Think of the Button as a class, whereas using the Button in the render function at a specific part of the DOM instantiates the class. When you pass your props to each button, it's like passing parameter's to your Button's constructor function. Not only is there no reason to have both be the same instance of "Button", its actually not possible given they are mounted to different places in the DOM.

Comment: If that doesn't make sense to you I recommend you read up a bit on how react interacts with the DOM and what you're actually doing when you place a `<Button />` component in your project.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you